# Problem with dot product and outer product of vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, convex-optimization

I have two column vectors $X$ and $Y$. Now the Equation is

$$
\frac{1}{2}(X Y^T)^2   - X^TXY^TY
$$

Where $X^T$ is the transpose of $X$.

I need to solve the equation  basically get something like $-\frac1{2}(X^TY)^2$

Edited Post

The full equation is like this.

$
     \iota(A,\tau) =  \frac{1}{2} (A-A_{t})^{2} + \tau(1-X^{T}.A.Y)
$

Where $\tau $ is the Langrangian Multiplier. We take the derivate w.r.t A and set the langrangian to 0. This yields

$ 
     A=A_{t} + \tau(X.Y^{T})
$

To find the value of $\tau$ we put value of A into the First Equation.

$ \iota(A,\tau) = \frac{1}{2}(\tau X.Y^{T})^2 + \tau -\tau(X^{T}.A_{t}.Y)-\tau^2(X^{T}.X.Y^{T}.Y)$

Now i need to simplify this so that i can diffrentiate it wrt to $\tau$ and finally to put the value of $\tau$ in the second equation. A is a square matrix

Comment: Well dimensions in your question does not match. $(X Y^T)^2 $ is matrix and $ X^TXY^TY  = \|X\|^2 \|Y\|^2$ is scalar. So you cant add those together.

Comment: I concur with tom's comment. And where is your *equation*? I only see an *expression*. An equation, by definition, *equates* one thing to another. Do you mean setting the displayed expression to zero?

Answer (score 1):

The given formula is an expression rather than an equation and the author wants to give it a different form. I assume that X(Y^T) is meant to be the inner product of X and Y. Let a be the angle between the two. Then the expression becomes 
(1/2)(|X|^2)(|Y|^2){cos(a)}^2- (|X|^2)(|Y|^2)
and it can be reformulated using trigonometric identities. But, in view of the factor 1/2, the outcome will not be the form the author suggests. One possible form is
-(1/2){(|X|^2)(|Y|^2)+(XxY)^2}
where x indicates the vector product.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please consider formatting your answers in LateX in future. You may learn by seeing some other answers.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I have added the full equation so the problem becomes clearer